# Is it possible to rotate the Isolines on a Surface Using `MeshFunction`?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

This came up in a different context but some expertise in 3D surfaces or the graphic options would be appreciated. I'm trying to extrapolate the curves from any given surface and things seem to be going quite smoothly. All the curves can be grabbed in one more step as a `GraphicsComplex`. Perfect for more processing. However, now I'm trying to rotate the isolines to get even more control. This is possible in other software but I'm not sure how it was achieved. I assume there is some way to use the `MeshFunction` to rotate the `Mesh` through at least 45 degrees but all my searching hasn't brought up anything helpful. A less practical approach might be to find the intersecting curve of a regularly spaced vertical planes.

```
Plot3D[Cos[(x y)/2], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 8},
BoxRatios->{4,8,1},
Boxed->False,
Axes->False,
ImageSize->Large,
Mesh->{3,8},
PlotStyle->Directive[Lighting->"Neutral",FaceForm[White,Specularity[0.2,10]]]]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since we have the identity

```
RotationMatrix[θ] == {AngleVector[-θ], AngleVector[π/2 - θ]}
```

one can use this to construct a mesh that is arbitrarily oriented; e.g.

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[Cos[x y/2], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 8}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
                  MeshFunctions -> {AngleVector[-θ].{#, #2} &,
                                    AngleVector[π/2 - θ].{#, #2} &},
                  PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighting -> "Neutral",
                                         FaceForm[White, Specularity[0.2, 10]]]],
           {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Manipulate demo]

Note that this rotates the mesh *clockwise*; use `MeshFunctions -> {AngleVector[θ].{#, #2} &, AngleVector[π/2 + θ].{#, #2} &}` instead if the anticlockwise version is desired.

Comment: (If anyone is kind enough to edit my post to include the resulting image, please do so.)

Comment: done (I took the liberty to replace the `With` with `Manipulate` to better show the advantages of this method)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Lukas! The `Manipulate[]` is indeed much nicer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `MeshFunctions -> (Function /@ (RotationMatrix[θ].{#, #2}))` to rotate by angle `θ`:

```
θ = 75 Degree;
meshfunctions = Function /@ (RotationMatrix[θ].{#, #2});

Plot3D[Cos[x y/2], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 8}, 
 MeshFunctions -> meshfunctions, Mesh -> {3, 8},
 BoxRatios -> {4, 8, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighting -> "Neutral", FaceForm[White, Specularity[0.2, 10]]]]
```

[image]

For `45 Degree` rotation you can use the simpler `MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &, # - #2 &}` to get

[image]