# Extracting Mesh lines from a GraphicsComplex

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometry

[image]

I was working on some geometric manipulation and hoping to further process this graphic's isolines however I was stumped as how best to do that when I looked at the object's `GraphicsComplex`. I was expecting to see something [similar to a question I asked last year about `Mesh` lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192157/is-it-possible-to-rotate-the-isolines-on-a-surface-using-meshfunction).

```
c = RevolutionPlot3D[{ x-0.2,-2 x},{x,0.7,1},
  Boxed->False,
  Axes->False,
  Mesh->{8,4}
]
c[[1,1,1,2]]
```

[image]

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 and tired the older function in the other thread too and it returns a similarly confusing `GraphicComplex`. 5 Dimensional polygons? Lines with one list for it's coordinates? I don't remember how I extracted the isolines.

Can someone describe to me how to extract the `Mesh` lines from a `GraphicsComplex`?

Comment: [A related thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22562)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need lines, you can take `Normal` and extract lines from it:

```
lines = Cases[Normal[c], _Line, Infinity];

Graphics3D[lines]
```

[image: mesh lines]

Answer (score 5):

To add to halmir's answer: if you don't need the surface, just use `PlotStyle -> None`:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{x - 0.2, -2 x}, {x, 0.7, 1}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                 Mesh -> {8, 4}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

which should give the same picture.

Note that this also includes the setting of `BoundaryStyle`; if you set it to `None`, you get this instead:

[image: mesh without boundary]

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
plot /. GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[p, Cases[g, _Line, Infinity]]
```

[image]

Comment: ...and one can of course take the complementary approach: `DeleteCases[plot, _Polygon, ∞]`